Iteration with openpyxl does not work with merged cells
I'd like write into an Excel sheet using the module openpyxl. I want to check whether the cells where I want to write something already have values. If so, I want to skip to the next row and write it there. Therefore I wrote the following code (I simplified it a lot).
When I execute the code, I get the following error:
'AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only'.
The code works totally fine with non-merged cells.
# Import Modules
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Define where to write data
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Write numbers from 1 to 20 in first row
for x in range(1, 20):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=x).value = x

# Define a list of Entries that shall be written to the Excel sheet
entries = [["Entry 1", 1, 5], ["Entry 2", 2, 6], ["Entry 3", 3, 7]]

# Check whether there are already values in the cells where I want to write and if so, skip to next line
for entry in entries:
    row = []
    for count_row in range(2, 5):
        has_value = []
        for count_column in range(entry[1], entry[2]+1):
            if ws.cell(row=count_row, column=count_column).value is None:
                has_value.append(False)
            else:
                has_value.append(True)
                break
        if True in has_value:
            continue
        else:
            row.append(count_row)
            break
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=row[0], start_column=entry[1], end_row=row[0], end_column=entry[2])
    ws.cell(row=row[0], column=entry[1]).value = entry[0]

# Save
wb.save("Test.xlsx")


The fact that the cells are merged shouldn't be a problem since I tried to make sure to only write into the first left cell of the merged cells.

You should [edit] and put the above comment in your Post, no need to add as a comment afterwards.

I gather you are attempting to determine if a row has existing values before merging cells and writing your list entry to the merge. I realise this is example code and it may only be for the [mre] but I'll make the comment; given the code creates the Workbook and Sheet, there is no reason to check if the 'new' row has values if you did not already write to the cells in the same program

The reason your code fails is due to the following;
On your 1st iteration it takes the list ["Entry 1", 1, 5] which translates to writing "Entry 1" into the merged cells from 1 to 5 (A to E) on the next row where these cells are tested as 'empty'. You start your checking from row 2 using cell row/column co-ordinates and given its a new Sheet this row will be empty and so A2:E2 is merged and the value written.
On the 2nd iteration you now have the list ["Entry 2", 2, 6] which translates to writing "Entry 2" into the merged cells from cols 2 to 6 (B to F) on the next row where these cells again test as 'empty'. You start with row 2 again but this time you are checking the cells from Column B. What I guess you dont realise is that the cell B2 still exists and can be referenced. Many of its usual attributes remain including .value and this attribute will be None, therefore passing your test.
I'll note here if the referenced cell or attribute did not exist your code would crash at this point anyway.
So all the cells you test in row 2 in the range B2 to F2 exist and all will have None as the value and pass your test. 
Your code then tries to merge that range, which will execute but corrupt your workbook in the process and then try to write the text to cell 'B2' at which you code crashes as cell B2 is a merged cell resulting in the error
'AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only'.
if you checked the cell types instead
        for count_column in range(entry[1], entry[2]+1):
            print(type(ws.cell(row=count_row, column=count_column)))  # <--- Add this line 
            if ws.cell(row=count_row, column=count_column).value is None:

you would see for each cell the type is
<class 'openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell'> 
except for the last cell which is not part of the previous merge. It's type will be
<class 'openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell'>
which is the type you'll see for all the cells A2:E5 on the 1st iteration
So you can see your test does not cover every eventuality that can cause a problems writing your data.
I don't know how sophisticated you want the check to be but certainly you can include the cell type check if you think that is necessary.
However one simple thing you could also do is skip the row your know your already wrote data to.
In you code rather than hardcoding the start of the row range as 2, use a variable that starts at the next row after the last one you used so after the 1st iteration when you wrote to row 2 the next start row should be 3.
    for count_row in range(2, 5):  # <--- Modify this range on each list iteration

This obviously means the end value of the range would need to be adjusted too as the start could possibly eventually be larger. 
However the method used here may not be the best anyway given your directive If so, I want Python to skip to the next row and write it there. What if rows 2, 3, 4 fail the test, do you want to stop there or keep going until you find a row for each of your list entries?

Like moken suggested, I checked for merged cells instead of checking if the cells have a value. If the cells are merged I conclude that these cells have a value and skip to the next row. Now it works totally fine. Here is my final code:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import MergedCell

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for x in range(1, 20):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=x).value = x

entries = [["Entry 1", 1, 5], ["Entry 2", 2, 6], ["Entry 3", 3, 7]]

for entry in entries:
    row = []
    for count_row in range(2, 5):
        has_value = []
        for count_column in range(entry[1], entry[2]+1):
            print(type(ws.cell(row=count_row, column=count_column)))
            if isinstance(ws.cell(row=count_row, column=count_column), MergedCell):
                has_value.append(True)
                break
            else:
                has_value.append(False)
        if True in has_value:
            continue
        else:
            row.append(count_row)
            break
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=row[0], start_column=entry[1], end_row=row[0], end_column=entry[2])
    ws.cell(row=row[0], column=entry[1]).value = entry[0]

# speichern
wb.save("Test.xlsx")


You could simplify this a lot more. Specifically, with reference to the MergedCells, get a list of these before you start and use it in your exclusion. But the rest would be a lot easier to read, and maintain, if you follow the examples in the documentation more closely. range(entry[1], entry[2]+1) eek! try range(entry[1:])
